# Calling Artisan Queue Retry from php

Tags: php, laravel, queue, beanstalkd

I am having issue about calling artisan queue from php.
I want to make the list of fail jobs in Beanstalkd queue and make a button to retry.

I want to call `php artisan queue:retry{id}`

So, I put this code in the route.php

```
Route::get('retry/{id}', function($id){
    Artisan::call("queue:retry $id");
});
```

And it return error

> InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Command "queue:retry 12" is
>   not defined.
>
> Did you mean one of these?
>       queue:retry
>       queue:forget
>       queue:failed-table
>       queue:flush
>       queue:failed
>       queue:listen
>       queue:subscribe
>       queue:work'

Any one can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Artisan::call('queue:retry', ['id' => $id]);`

**Update:** (thanks to the @BakerStreetSystems's answer below)

```
Artisan::call('queue:retry', ['id' => [$id]]);
```

Answer (score 7):

I just tried limonte's answer and though it was very close to what I needed, I noted that the `RetryCommand.php` expects the `id` value to be an array, so you need to have an embedded array like this:

```
Artisan::call('queue:retry', ['id' => [$id]]);
```

Comment: This answer is correct, and definitely not fun to troubleshoot.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/RetryCommand.php#L30-L41

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/RetryCommand.php#L94